# why the maximum of this function is this?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the folowing surface
\begin{equation}
  f(x,y)= 2x^3 - 3y^2 + x^2 + 5
\end{equation}

By finding the critical points one can see that there is a maximum
at the point $(-1/3,0)$ with the value $136/27 \approx 5.04$. Even 
[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximum%202x%5E3%20-%203y%5E2%20%2B%20x%5E2%20%2B%205) will tell you that.

Yet the point (1,0) produces the value $2+1+5=8$ which is greater than
$5.04$. Why this point does not appear in the "radar" of the critical
points (where the partial derivatives vanish). Why could even WolframAlpha not spot it?

It is true that the point $(1,0)$ is not critical. However let us
assume the region $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$. If you use the parametrization
$x=\cos t, y = \sin t$, you will find the equation
\begin{equation}
  \cos t \sin t( 3 \cos t + 4) = 0
\end{equation}
from which $t=0$ and then $x=1$, $y=0$ is a solution.
Yet if you choose the parametrization $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$,
you will find the equation
\begin{equation}
   x(3 x +4) = 0
\end{equation}
and $x=1$ is not a solution for this equation. Note that if
you change $x$ by $x=\cos t$ this equation is "almost" the other
except for the $\sin t$ which is in the first but not in this.
Why is that? why the parametrization $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ does not 
let me find this absolute maximum? and the parametrization
$x=\cos t$, $y=\sin t$ does?

Thanks

Comment: As x gets to be large f(x,0) goes to infinity.  This will not appear as a maximum (unless you close the domain.)

Comment: Good point.  I will reformulate the question.

Comment: What Wolfram Alpha says about this maximum is that it is a local maximum, not a global one.

Answer (score 2):

> Why doesn't the parametrization $y=\sqrt{1−x^2}$ not let me find this absolute maximum?

Firstly, $(1,0)$ isn't a global maximum; it's a maximum in a certain domain, but it's not an *absolute*. By the looks of it, $f$ increases without bound as $x$ increases.

Now, regarding the parametrizations:

Using $x=\cos t,y=\sin t$, we get $$2 (\cos t)^3 - 3 (\sin t)^2 + (\cos t)^2 + 5$$ which becomes $$5 - 3 \cos^2 t + \sin^2 t + 2 \sin^3t$$ Choosing values of $t$ that correspond to $(1,0)$ will give $8$.

**Remark:** this maximum in the region given by the region $x^2+y^2≤1$ will *not* show up by solving for when the derivative is zero because it is *not* a *critical point*. This is why it is often said that when you are finding min/maxima in a domain, you must check the values of a function at the endpoints of the domain as well as at the critical points in the domain.

Now, using $y=\sqrt{1−x^2}$, $$2 x^3 - 3 y^2 + x^2 + 5$$ becomes $$2 x^3 - 3 \big(\sqrt{1−x^2}\big)^2 + x^2 + 5$$ or $$2 (1 + 2 x^2 + x^3)$$ and we get $f(1) = 8$, as needed.

Comment: AinaThanks for your answer. My question was incomplete. Could you please look at it now?

Comment: I've edited it. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: I think I understand. The parametrization $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is defined in the interval $[0,1]$ and both $0$ and $1$ are end points no interior. However when using $x=\cos t$, $y=\sin t$ we could say that $t \in[-\pi,\pi]$ instead of $t \in [0, 2 \pi]$ so that $0$ would not be an end point, is this why the parametrization $x=\cos t$, $y=\sin t$ always work? Thanks.

Comment: Correct. And it also works because it has no discontinuities.

Comment: I meant $x \in [-1,1]$  and 1 and -1 end points.